# Rendered Background video is B/W any ideas why?

Tags: rendering, camera

I wanted to create a Muzzle Flare effect for a video of a friend (250 frames long)and managed to create the Flare effect using a Cylinder and some cloud deformation + emission. I´ve then set the video as a background video to the camera and placed my object at specific Keyframes making it appear for only for 1 keyframe (3 in total) but once  rendered,(Eevee) the video in the background appears in a kind of Black/White/Sepa-ish color. Video is sRGB though.

Any ideas how to get the original colors ?

I thought of maybe importing it as a plane and using it with Nodes.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not into vers 2.8 but in earlier versions the background image/video feature would default to half opacity. It had to be wound up. You might have the same or similar happening there?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm going to check this out :D